# Запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

**Если ты хочешь стать ведущим, репортёром, готов заняться съёмкой и режиссурой или ты фотографируешь, пишешь сценарии( ) одним словом, желаешь применить свои навыки и способности – будем рады тебе.**

Answer (score 1):

Ставится тире, так как вначале идет однородный ряд, а потом обобщающие слова *"желаешь применить..."* Вводная конструкция *"одним словом"* указывает на то, что далее следуют обобщающие слова.

---

Я считаю не очень обоснованным последнее тире. Отделение придаточной от главной происходит при помощи запятой, но никак не тире.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, у Розенталя есть интересное правило о т.н. периоде, когда большое предложение делится на 2 части, причем во второй части делается вывод из того, о чем говорилось в первой. В таком случае ставится запятая и тире (,- будем рады тебе). Что касается вводной конструкции "одним словом" (=следовательно), то ее вполне можно выделить только запятыми, ведь слова "желаешь применить свои навыки и способности" можно считать обобщающими лишь с большой натяжкой.

Answer (score 0):

Если после однородных придаточных предложений стоит обобщающее слово с предшествующим вводным словом или словосочетанием (словом,   и т.п.), то перед последним ставится запятая и тире, а после него – запятая,  например: На одном из перегонов разговорились про частные дела, кто откуда, чем занимался, в какой среде вырос, – словом, на темы бескрайние (Фурманов).

Если ты хочешь стать ведущим, репортёром, готов заняться съёмкой и режиссурой или ты фотографируешь, пишешь сценарии, - одним словом, желаешь применить свои навыки и способности, будем рады тебе.